# ios How to properly use NSPredicate for NSString matching with Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, match, nspredicate

I'm trying to insert or update(if it exists) an entity into Core Data with the following code:

```
- (void)insertFriendWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)friendInfo {

    NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Friend"];

    NSString *atributeName = @"identifier";
    NSString *valueName = [[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",atributeName,valueName ];
    req.predicate = predicate;

    req.fetchLimit = 1;
    NSError *requestError = nil;
    NSArray *tmp = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&requestError];

    if (tmp && tmp.count >0) {
        Friend *friend = [tmp objectAtIndex:0];
        friend.name = [friendInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
        friend.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5]];
        [self saveContext];
        return;
    }   

    Friend *friend = 
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friend"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    friend.name = [friendInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
    friend.identifier = [friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"];
    friend.noOfMessagesReceived = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    friend.email = @"";
    friend.selected = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    friend.frooiFriend = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
}
```

But the predicate doesn't match any result when runiing the code the second time. I beleive it's a problem with the NSPredicate.

Here is the code generated for Friend:

```
@interface Friend : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * frooiFriend;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * noOfMessagesReceived;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * profileImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * selected;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * frooliMessagesSentTo;

@end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it seems first you execute the request then you insert the object, thus after the first run, you executed the request on an empty data structure (the result is `0` which is correct) then you inserted a new `NSManagedObject`, the result would be `1` now, but you are not requesting the current database. try to first insert the new `NSManagedObject` and then execute the request. what do you think?

Comment: i think the logic i used is good. tilo poited out the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"]` equal to `[[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5]`?

If not: this is your problem, as you are setting `friend.identifier = [friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"];` for a new friend, but your predicate for searching for a friend uses `[[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ MATCHES[cd] '.*%@.*'",atributeName,valueName ];
```

It's not the best for performance, but it works. You can improve performance afterwards.